# Manipulating Column in DataTable C#

Tags: c#, datatable

Am using `DataTable` in C# and am trying to manipulate, modify one of the column. Consider sample data below

```
Id     City Temperature
-------------------
1       A   -12

2       B    23

3       C    12
```

And after conversion i want the below result where am converting Minus to M and Positive values to P

```
Id     City Temperature
-------------------------
1       A    12M

2       B    23P

3       C    12P
```

Can i achieve this using LINQ..Am parsing this with around 50k Rows and dont want to compromise on performance.what are the other best ways  ?

Comment: Is the `Temperature`-columns's data type `int`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Datatype -  Double

Comment: so you want to create a new datatable with a new column where the data-type is string?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Exactly but prefer same DataTable by converting the datatype !!  is it possible to change the DataType also fine!!

Comment: No, it's not possible to change the type of a column of a filled `DataTable`. I've provided an answer which shows how to create a new table.

Comment: if you want to display as such it's up to the view to show positive as [0-9] + P and negative as ABS([0-9]) + M.

Comment: Do you only visualize this within a DataGridView or do you have to process this data any further?

Comment: @Oliver Am passing this to JQGRID as json with other required parameters

Comment: Don't know much about this stuff, but is there any possibility to intercept the creation of the json string? In that case you could write your integer value in any format you like when the json will be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column is `string` instead of `double`/`int`:

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    string temp = row.Field<string>("Temperature");
    bool negative = temp.StartsWith("-");
    temp = negative ? temp.Substring(1) + "M" : temp + "P";
    row.SetField("Temperature", temp);
}
```

If the column type is `double` - as mentioned now - you have to create a new `DataTable`. You cannot change the `DataType` after the `Datatable` is filled with data.

```
DataTable newTable = table.Clone();
int ordinal = newTable.Columns.IndexOf("Temperature");;
newTable.Columns.Remove("Temperature");  // remove double-column
DataColumn tempCol = newTable.Columns.Add("Temperature"); // string
tempCol.SetOrdinal(ordinal); 
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    DataRow newRow = newTable.Rows.Add();
    foreach(DataColumn col in newTable.Columns)
    {
        if (col == tempCol)
        {
            double temp = row.Field<double>("Temperature");
            bool negative = temp < 0;
            double abs = Math.Abs(temp);
            string newTemp = negative ? abs.ToString() + "M" : abs.ToString() + "P";
            newRow.SetField(col, newTemp);
        }
        else
            newRow.SetField(col, row[col.ColumnName]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter Will take a look !!! +1 will mark answer after   i resolve this !! Thanks again!!